# disable fields if query is true

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to disable fields of a modal if the result of a query is true, I have an idea of ​​how to do it, but I have not been able to specify it, I would appreciate any help or correction within my code:

controller

```
    function evaluarTrabajador(){

    $this->load->model("Prwtrabajadores_model");

    $idTrabajador = $this->input->post('idEdit');

    $this->Prwtrabajadores_model->revisaCertificados($idTrabajador);

    }
```

model

```
    function revisaCertificados($idTrabajador){

    return $this->db
        ->select("a.idprw_estadocertificado")
        ->from("prw_estadocertificado as a")
        ->join($this->schemaEmpresas."wom_trabajadores as b")
        ->where("b.idwom_trabajadores", $idTrabajador)
        ->where("a.idprw_estadocertificado = 1 || 4 || 5")
        ->get()->result();
        $query = result();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }
       }
```

and the JS from view, now the JS show the data from database, but need block the text fields if the query is true

```
$(".editarT").on("click", function(id){

    var id = $(this).data("idtra");

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('/contratista/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {   

            $('input[name="idEdit"]').val(data[0].idwom_trabajadores);
            $('input[name="rutEdit"]').val(data[0].rut);
            $('input[name="nombresEdit"]').val(data[0].nombres);
            $('input[name="appEdit"]').val(data[0].apellido_paterno);
            $('input[name="apmEdit"]').val(data[0].apellido_materno);
            $('input[name="cargoEdit"]').val(data[0].cargo);
            $('input[name="telefonoEdit"]').val(data[0].telefono);
            $('input[name="mutualEdit"]').val(data[0].mutual);
            $('#form-modal-editar-trabajador').modal({show:true});  
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error obteniendo datos');
        }
    });

   });
```

Comment: i didn't understand clearly ,What i got from your QS. If the ans is like that ,then i suggest you to try it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp

Comment: In your json response, add a property - query_result - which is either success or not. Then in your ajax success handler do, if(data.query_status == 'success'){...} - there you disable whichever fields you like.

Comment: Or if by query true means you have data retrieved, then just check the length of data via `data[0].length > 0` for query true.

Comment: @KarloKokkak i don't understand, do you can explain a few more?

Comment: In your ajax success handler, if data[0].length > 0, then disable the fields needed to be disabled.

Comment: Is your ajax call receiving the required record with the current code?

Comment: You want to disable all the input text fields if data is there ? @AlvaroVergara

Comment: @RanjithM yes, i need show the info, but don't let edit it to the users,

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$(".editarT").on("click", function(id){

    var id = $(this).data("idtra");

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('/contratista/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {   

            $('#form-modal-editar-trabajador').modal({show:true});  
            if(data.length > 0){
                $('input[name="idEdit"]').val(data[0].idwom_trabajadores).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="rutEdit"]').val(data[0].rut).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="nombresEdit"]').val(data[0].nombres).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="appEdit"]').val(data[0].apellido_paterno).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="apmEdit"]').val(data[0].apellido_materno).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="cargoEdit"]').val(data[0].cargo).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="telefonoEdit"]').val(data[0].telefono).prop('disabled', true);
                $('input[name="mutualEdit"]').val(data[0].mutual).prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else{
                $('input[name="idEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="rutEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="nombresEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="appEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="apmEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="cargoEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="telefonoEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
                $('input[name="mutualEdit"]').val('').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error obteniendo datos');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: is a good idea, but i need make the evaluation with a query diferent of the query that bring me the info, is a query that just evaluate if the state is true or false